# Expectation problem of a stochastic integral

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I have a question for the following equation:
$$ E[B_t^2 \int_{0}^{t} 2s B_s dB_s]= 4 \int_{0}^{t}s^2 ds =4/3t^3 $$
i know about the Ito isometry formula but I don't know what happened with this $B_t^2$.
I hope someone can explain me this, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You have by Ito's formula: 
\begin{equation}
B_t^2 = \int_0^t 2B_sdB_s + t
\end{equation}
Hence, 
\begin{align}
E[B_t^2\int_0^t 2 sB_sdB_s] &= E[(\int_0^t 2B_sdB_s + t)\int_0^t 2sB_sdB_s]\\
&= E[(\int_0^t 2B_sdB_s\int_0^t 2sB_sdB_s)] + t\underbrace {E[\int_0^t 2sB_sdB_s]}_{=0} \\
&=4\int_0^t sE[B_s^2]ds \quad \text{By isometry} \\
&= 4 \int_0^ts^2ds.\\
\end{align}
Note that we have $E[\int_0^t 2B_sdB_s]=0$  (Explain why ?)

Comment: First, thank you for your help! @sesame

Comment: to your question, this expectation is 0 because $ E[\int_{s}^{t} 2B_s dB_s]=\int_s^t 2E[B_s]dB_s $. Now $B_s$ is $N(0,s)$, hence this expactation is 0 and we get your equation. Am i right?

Comment: @Gaus123 The left-hand side of your equation is the expectation of a random variable, i.e., a number. The right-hand side is a stochastic integral evaluated at a point in time, i.e. a random variable. Of course, $E[B_s]$ being $0$ *does* end up making the whole thing an equality, but the stochastic integral and the expectation never commute otherwise. The point is that $\int_s^t 2Bs \textrm{d}Bs$ is the probability limit of mean $0$ Gaussians and hence, is either a.s. $0$ or a mean $0$ Gaussian.